# Is adding an index to a WordPress meta table a bad idea?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, indexing, woocommerce

I'm currently utilizing the `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table in WordPress (set up similarly to `wp_postmeta`). This table has four fields:

- `id`
- `order_item_id`
- `meta_key`
- `meta_value`

I've got a situation where I need to make sure meta_values for certain meta_keys are unique. E.g. ticket numbers (same ticket number can't be issued twice).

I know it's possible to use multiple-column indexes with unique constraints:

- [Understanding multiple column indexes in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728832/understanding-multiple-column-indexes-in-mysql-query)
- [How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)

My question is: would adding such a constraint affect performance or have any weird side-effects in WordPress that anyone can think of?

Comment: **Yes very bad idea** - You should not in any way make that kind of changes in existing database tables that Wordpress / Woocommerce are using. If you set `meta_keys` and/or `meta_values` to be unique in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`, Woocommerce orders will not work anymore. So you should better create a new custom table where you will be able to do whatever you want.

Comment: _Woocommerce orders will not work anymore._ Even with a three-column unique constraint? E.g. add a constraint across 'order_item_id', 'meta_key', and 'meta_value'. Although there are some cases where multiple values are desirable for a particular meta_key, and `wc_get_order_item_meta` would get an array of values for a particular meta_key.

Answer (score 0):

"Ticket number" should be its own column, not an "attribute".  Then you can apply a uniqueness constraint safely.

Meanwhile, there are multiple inefficiencies in `wp_postmeta`, as discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta).

Comment: I totally agree that ticket number should be its own column, but one should *not* add additional columns to `wp_postmeta`, as [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) would not be able to be used for this additional column.

Comment: @DonTownsend - Not to `postmeta`; add `ticket_num` to `post`.